# Chrome Bluetooth API function for if uuid is present, change div visibility

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I am just experimenting with some of the sample functions of the bluetooth api from Chrome. I am attempting to alter the code from the available samples to fit with a function that will adjust div visibility properties based on proximity of a specified beacon. The code below *hypothetically* requests service from the device on page ready.

```
$(document).ready(function onButtonClick() {
let serviceUuid = 'EDF094632432432D9C585014E22E7073';
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({filters: [{services: [serviceUuid]}]})
.then(device => {
return device.gatt.connect();
})
.then(server => {
return server.getPrimaryService(serviceUuid);
})  
})
```

Does anyone know if the Chrome Bluetooth API has any functions for determining proximity of a device? If so, could you direct me to some documentation that I can review.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `EDF094632432432D9C585014E22E7073` is not a valid Bluetooth GATT UUID.

Regarding your initial question, there is no way as of March 2017 to scan BLE advertisement packets (eg. beacon). At some point, Web Bluetooth scanning should be implemented: https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/scanning

Comment: Thanks Francois. This device id is listed in the management console for Gimbal. Any thoughts on how I might track down the valid UUID?  Also, I have been researching the Chrome BT Api and there are some event listeners that can respond to a change in a ble device characteristic I may be able to add an event listener where the change in a characteristic can be a catalyst for a change in a div property.

Comment: Device ID in Gimbal is certainly not what you're looking for. I'd recommend you read https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/introduction and https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web first.